Node.js fetch with ProxyAgent from undici never gets response (axios works)
I want in a Node.js project to perform a simple fetch request with proxy by specifically using ProxyAgent from undici and native fetch but i can't get it to work. The request never resolves or rejects and the first console.log of the proxy code never runs. Other ways like using axios or http.get or even postman do work. Am i doing something wrong? Does undici proxy for some reason works only with certain proxies?
index.js
import { ProxyAgent } from "undici";

const client = new ProxyAgent("http://127.0.0.1:8000");

fetch("http://ifconfig.io/ip", {
  dispatcher: client,
  method: "GET",
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Got response");
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error("response not ok");
    }
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("Response Data = ", data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error.message);
  });

Code of a simple proxy with Node.js (which works fine with postman and axios)
proxy.js
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const url = require('url');

// Create a proxy server
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

// Create an HTTP server that will use the proxy
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log("Original request URL:", req.url);
  
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
  // The target is set directly to the desired backend service
  const target = `${parsedUrl.protocol}//${parsedUrl.host}`; 

  // Proxy the request to the target server
  proxy.web(req, res, { target });

  // Log the proxied request
  console.log(`Proxied request to: ${target}`);
});

// Listen on a specific port (e.g., 8000)
const PORT = 8000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Dynamic proxy server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Tried to also import fetch from undici but same results.
In case it helps i run this in Node.js LTS version 20.17.0 (also tried in 18.18.2) and this my package.json
{
  "name": "nodejs-proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type":"module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.4",
    "http-proxy": "^1.18.1",
    "http-proxy-agent": "^7.0.2",
    "undici": "^6.19.8"
  }
}

Working example with axios.
indexAxios.js
import axios from "axios";

axios.get('https://ifconfig.io/ip', {
  proxy: {
    protocol: "http",
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8000,
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Response data:', response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error.message);
  });

Also tried this proxy same results
import http from "http";
import request from "request";

const PORT = 8000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(`Incoming request to ${req.url}`);
  req.pipe(request(req.url)).pipe(res);
}).listen(PORT);

Also tried the following proxy which again works just fine with axios but when i use it with the fetch example it just bypasses it and gets a response. (fetched data from an http mock api because it didn't like https)
import * as http from 'http';
import { createProxy } from 'proxy';

const server = createProxy(http.createServer());

// Log each incoming request
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Incoming request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
});

server.listen(3128, () => {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('HTTP(s) proxy server listening on port %d', port);
});


I thought that as of Node.js version 20 you can just use the native fetch though
Make a request in native Fetch with Proxy in NodeJS 18

If this is true then why when i use it (dispatcher: client) in Node.js version 20.17.0 the request never gets resolved or rejected? While if i use for example banana: client in the options (where fetch does not know what banana is) the request resolves just fine (without going through a proxy)? This hints to me that somehow it tries to use this dispatcher i pass to it.

Oh, wait ... native fetch does understand dispatcher - not documented as far as I can see - some part of undici is internal to nodejs it seems - indeed the node fetch is undici

I'll remove my comments, as they are invalid

it may be that your simple proxy is somehow not "compatible" with ProxyAgent - using this simple proxy your code works 100%

I tried this proxy and also added
server.on('request', (req, res) => {   console.log("Incoming request:", req.url); });
to have some logs. The axios works with it (i see the log) but the fetch gets a response but it bypasses the proxy like i never used it. It is interesting to me that with the first proxy it never gets a response but with this proxy it just bypasses it and gets a response. Thank you for help btw :)

the proxy I posted the link to works just fine with undici ProxyAgent

Can you post an answer with versions etc so i can accept it? I tried it but did not see any log ("Incoming request") witch undici fetch, while with axios i saw it.

I used the code in the link to create the proxy. Why would I need to post an answer when you say that code doesn't work

If you've run the proxy and made a request through it with undici successfully if i use the exact same versions (OS, Node.js, undici, proxy) and code it has to work. Also you get points with an answer!

oh wow. points!

Do you want to make an HTTP request (like in index.js) or an HTTPS request (like in indexAxios.js)? The following answer is about HTTPS requests.
Behavior of fetch
HTTP and HTTPS requests made by fetch are much different when proxies are involved.
If the fetch statement in your index.js makes an HTTPS request through a proxy, it first sends a CONNECT request
CONNECT ifconfig.io:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: ifconfig.io:443
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

to http://localhost:8000.
But your proxy.js server is not prepared to handle such CONNECT requests. It must contain an event handler like
server.on("connect", function(request, socket, head) {
  // request.url = "ifconfig.io:443"
  var s = net.createConnection({host: "ifconfig.io", port: 443}, function() {
    socket.write("HTTP/1.1 200\r\n\r\n");
    s.pipe(socket);
    s.write(head);
  });
  socket.once("data", function(data) {
    s.write(data);
    socket.pipe(s);
  });
});

The handler establishes a connection with the target host and forwards all subsequent (encrypted) traffic that goes over the same connection ("SSL tunneling").
The other proxies you tried seem to lack such a CONNECT handler as well (what you call "it didn't like https").
Behavior of axios
axios does not use SSL tunneling. Instead of a CONNECT request it makes the following request (unencrypted) to http://localhost:8080:
GET https://ifconfig.io/ip HTTP/1.1
host: ifconfig.io
Connection: keep-alive

Your proxy.js server then forwards this as a separate HTTPS request, but since the request from browser to proxy is HTTP only, the request made by axios is not end-to-end encrypted. For example, the "path portion" of the URL, (/ip) is transmitted unencrypted between browser and proxy and so is the response to this request.
(By contrast, the unencrypted CONNECT request does not contain the entire URL, only the host.)
